# Reload xhtml files on demand in myfaces 2.0 application

Tags: jsf, xhtml, reload, myfaces

we're delevoping a JSF application with MyFaces 2.1.

For reloading xhtml on-the-fly, we set

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This works fine, but slows down the application (about times 5 compared to value -1. For production it's set to -1 of course). 
This makes me wondering if there's any way to change this parameter on demand. Thus I could set it to -1 and create something like a servlet in order to trigger the xhtml reload.

Is something like this possible or has anyone an idea for refreshing xhtml on demand?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using some IDE to develop your JSF application? Are you sure the facelet refresh problem is exactly in the framework caching and not in your IDE not properly publishing files or in your playground browser caching the old contents? I don't use MyFaces, but what I actually do in Mojarra is to set the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` parameter in `production` or `development`. In order to avoid having to change it by hand when you need to deploy it, use a build tool like Maven, Ant or Graddle (with different profiles).

Comment: I'm using eclipse for developing, the application is build by maven. The xhtml-files are refreshed, but the whole applications gets very slow when the refreh-period is not set to -1. Setting the project Stage to "development" makes it even worse. That's why I was wondering if I could refresh them on demand.